# flutter show modal bottom sheet to share application

Tags: flutter, package, modal-dialog, share

How can i show this kind of modal bottom sheet ? that contains list of applications and the user can share the application after choosing one of the list ? is there a package to implement it ?

[image]

Comment: [flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share)

Answer (score 2):

use This library
[flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following plugin to achieve this.
[Share Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)

With full example here
[Example](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example)

The others mentioned like [flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) and [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SHARE_PLUS](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package for share as below:

```
Future<void> _handleSharePressed() async {
final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
String myList = 'MY_LIST';

await Share.share(myList,
        subject: 'YOUR_SUBJECT',
        sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);

 }
```